# Does JavaScript prototype works between parent/iframe's contexts?

Tags: javascript, prototype, boundary

I'm building a web-based code editor and ran into trouble handling focus.
It's obvious that I need to move into iframe for every editor instance.
However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use JavaScript's prototype-based
inheritance in this case.

Basically, I need included script to contain prototype definition and every
object serving specific iframe use this single prototype.

From this point I have two ideas:

1. Objects serving iframes should be hosted in a top window.
2. Objects serving iframes should be hosted in child iframe's windows.

What is the best way to handle this situation? I'm not sure how to
correctly deal with JavaScript context boundary...

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting, but what do you mean by "using prototype based inheritance across frames"? If you mean inheriting from the same object, you can just put it in an external .js file, so you probably don't mean that. Do you mean you want to access global objects? I think you can do that by accessing window.parent[property] from the child iFrame. Is that it?

Comment: Basically, I'm taking CodePress as a base point and in there it's not considered. With CodePress if you instantiate 10 editors, it will create 10 iframes. Each of those iframes will have it's own serving object and prototype isn't used meaning all functions are copied and stored in-memory. 

What I need is single prototype for all instances of serving objects. Still experimenting...

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. It will take some work and you may have to make some changes to your source.

To start with, you have to make sure you never use window.document in any of the code. You are dealing with multiple documents and they can't share nodes. You can make use of [node].ownerDocument though, that way you will have cross frame safe node interaction. I haven't worked with CodePress before, but I wouldn't be surprised if it can't work across frames in this fashion.

Also, there are some issues with IE and objects/functions cross frame. As I recall, sometimes function get converted to objects and then can't actually be called, and detecting that involves using the toString and comparting it to "[object Object]"